# Is metal a conductor?

Tags: soldering, short-circuit

[image: An arduino connected by pins to a surface of unknown metal. The pins are labeled "ground" and "battery input"]

I'm very new to electrical engineering, and I wanted to ask a question before I attempted something potentially dumb.

I need to connect this Arduino to this slab of metal jewelry so that it's secure enough for me to plug and unplug a USB in without shearing the Arduino off the jewelry. I was going to solder it directly on (and probably use a few more pins elsewhere to stabilize.) I don't know what type of metal this surface this is, but I know it's non-magnetic (guessing it could be copper of some sort, though potentially it could also brass or bronze I think. I found this jewelry on the side of the road.)

Anyway, I was wondering if this could potentially cause a problem - like a short-circuit. In the picture, I have a battery pack and an Arduino connected by these 3 pins. The middle pin is the ground, and the right-side pin is the battery input (sending voltage from the battery pack into the rduino,) and the left pin sends voltage from the Arduino USB to the battery pack. All three would be soldered to the metal in this scenario (assuming the soldering goes well.)

Comment: All metals are conductor.

Comment: not potentially a short circuit .... definitely a short circuit ... if you solder three pins to the same piece of metal, then that would be the same as twisting the three pins together and soldering them

Comment: Have you considered using 2 part epoxy glue? Should be able to get some for a dollar or two.

Comment: epoxy glue! good idea - didn't think of that

Comment: If it's just a temporary job for a costume or something, electrical tape will give more than enough insulation for low voltages.  If you use it right it will last quite a while.  If it's more permanent other options would be better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My answer got deleted by a moderator so let me be clear - based on the comments - YES this CAN CAUSE A SHORT CIRCUIT.

Comment: It probably got deleted because answers who simply say "yes" are considered very low quality. A good answer in this case would contain a solution too.